# Adding hyperlink to document to redirect on parent document set in the search view

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, client-object-model, csom

Environment: SharePoint Online

My scenario is based on a Document Library - Document Set - Document hierarchy. In this case my view is showing the documents without the parent document set (folder). In some cases, the users need to have direct access to the parent document set. However, this action should not access the document set (folder) from the inside (document view) but rather see the search results as I would when searching the document set name using the 'Find a file' tool of the library.

```
DocumentSetName - Order20304

Document View:

testdoc1 GoToLink DocDetail1 DocDetail2
testdoc2 GoToLink DocDetail2 DocDetail3
```

If I search in the 'Find a file' search facility of the document library, I get a URL which looks like this:

https://root.sharepoint.com/Orders/Forms/AllItems.aspx#InplviewHash418848bb-be11-4c2c-8x95-3e73652f4794=WebPartID%3D%7B418848BB--BE11--4C2C--8F95--3E73653F4794%7D

This link filters the view to show all the document sets and documents which has a column that contains the document set name, which is exactly what I want to achieve.

Question 1: What makes up the link? Can someone break it up for me? I would like to programmatically create the column using any tool (for e.g. I am using CSOM regularly to customise the system).

Question 2: How would I be able to expose the link from the column as a hyperlink so the users can click on the link from the view (without having to access the ViewAllProperties form). I don't mind if this has to also be set programmatically.

Thanks in advance!